# Insert into database a scraped page containing double quotes with MySQL and Java

Tags: java, mysql

Imagine my page has a bunch of  sections looking something like this ([example page](http://www.iii.co.uk/investment/detail?code=cotn%3aHER.L&display=news&it=le)):

```
  <div class="content">
    </div>
```

My goal is to  scrape the entire page into a MySQL DB entry. I currently do this like so:

```
        //Declare SQL statement
    String sql = "INSERT into rns " + 
            "(rns_pub_date, rns_headline, rns_link, rns_fulltext, constituent_id) values (\""+
            rns.getRnsPubDate() + "\",\"" +
            rns.getRnsHeadline() + "\",\"" +
            rns.getRnsLink() + "\",\"" +
            rns.getRnsFullText() + "\",\"" +
            "(select constituent_id from constituent where constituent_name = " + rns.getRnsConstituentName() + "\")";



    //SQL Statement Debug
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "createRns. sqlStatement: " + sql);


    //Initialize insertValues
    insertValues = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
```

However, this falls over because there are multiple " marks in the page.

I can see a few options:

1. Escape the characters like this: '**\"**'
2. Replace the characters with: '**"**'
3. Remove all non-relevant data (the HTML) and save only the relevant data to the DB

I realise that there's also best practice with regards to preventing SQL injection. However this is a standalone system, so for the moment isn't an issue. Having said that if any answer can explain how to prevent that, I would prefer to implement that instead.

**Edit 1:**
Following on from @chrylis comment. This is what I have:

```
    //Insert values into variables
    String rns_pub_date = rns.getRnsPubDate();
    String rns_headline = rns.getRnsHeadline();
    String rns_link = rns.getRnsLink();
    String rns_fulltext = rns.getRnsFullText();
    String rns_constituent_name = rns.getRnsConstituentName();

    //Prepare the SQL string
    String sql = "INSERT into rns (rns_pub_date, rns_headline, rns_link, rns_fulltext,constituent_id) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,(select constituent_id from constituent where constituent_name = \"" + rns.getRnsConstituentName() + "\")";

    //Prepare the statement
    PreparedStatement prest = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    prest.setString(1, rns_pub_date);
    prest.setString(2, rns_headline);
    prest.setString(3, rns_link);
    prest.setString(4, rns_fulltext);
    prest.setString(5, rns_constituent_name);
```

However it provides this error:

```
Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4).
```

**Edit 2:**

The insert was fixed by removing the escaped double quotes for the 5th parameter:

```
String sql = "INSERT into rns (rns_pub_date, rns_headline, rns_link, rns_fulltext, constituent_id) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,(select constituent_id from constituent where constituent_name = ?))";
```

Comment: "I realise that I'm shooting myself in the foot but is there any way to make it hurt less?"

Comment: @BoristheSpider... Useful. <Smiley Face>

Comment: Why are you *still* using string pasting instead of parameterizing `constituent_name`?

Comment: @chrylis. Thanks for the spot. Pasted the old line in to the second Edit. Now have the actual new line pasted into the second Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement, there will be no need for escaping. Usage example is in API

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the best way forward, however I'm still having issues. Update above.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only a bad practice because of SQL injection, it's slow and inefficient, too, and has problems with quote characters. Use a parameterized query.